# The radius of convergence of $\sum \left(\frac{z^2-1}{z^2+1}\right)^n$

Tags: complex-analysis, divergent-series

I'm trying to find the radius of convergence of complex series
$$S=\sum_0^\infty\left(\frac{z^2-1}{z^2+1}\right)^n$$
with the help of ratio test.

With simple observation that the term $a_n$ become singular when
$$z^2+1=0\rightarrow z=\pm i$$
The radius of convergence should be $1$. But I want to find this with ratio test:

First, I assume
$$\zeta=\frac{z^2-1}{z^2+1}\rightarrow S=\sum_0^\infty \zeta^n$$
This series have radius of convergence
$$R=\lim_{n\rightarrow \infty}\left|\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}}\right|=1$$
$$\left|\frac{z^2-1}{z^2+1}\right|<1$$
I don't how this implies that $R<1$. Also, I'm sure if this method is correct. Please help me with this.

Comment: There's a small error in your last display.  $$\frac{a_n}{a_{n+1}} = \frac{z^2 + 1}{z^2 - 1}  \text{.}  $$

Answer (score 1):

The "radius of convergence" is a notion applying to power series. I don't think your series apply to this category.

$$\left|\frac{z^2-1}{z^2+1}\right|<1 \Longleftrightarrow \left|z^2-1\right| < \left|z^2+1\right|$$
which means $z^2$ is closer to $-1$ than to $1$ in the complex plane. This is equivalent to $\Re(z^2)<0$, or $|x|<|y|$ if you write $z=x+iy$.

The locus of points $z$ such that your series converges is the union of the open quarter-planes corresponding to those inequations. The shape of this locus proves that your series have nothing in common with power series.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I think, $|z^2-1|<|z^2+1|$ means $z^2$ is closer to $+1$ than to $-1$. Also, this means that assertion that the radius of convergence is the distance to the nearest singularity is not valid here.

Comment: You're right for the first point. My mistake. For the second, the notion of "radius of convergence" doesn't apply here : the convergence domain isn't a disk !